# After pressing the sign up button the email and password are saved in firebase even if the username text field was empty

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, validation

Here is the code from sign up view controller

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var userNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        userNameTextField.backgroundColor = .clear
        userNameTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 27
        userNameTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        userNameTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGreen.cgColor
        
        emailTextField.backgroundColor = .clear
        emailTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 27
        emailTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        emailTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGreen.cgColor
        
        passwordTextField.backgroundColor = .clear
        passwordTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 27
        passwordTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        passwordTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGreen.cgColor
    }
```

And here is the code that must be executed after pressing the sign up button, but if I fill in password and email but not the username it throws an error and it still saves the data without username and after I try to sign up with the same email it says that this email already exists, even though username was empty

```
@IBAction func signupPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text {
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
                if let e = error {
                    self.errorLabel.text = e.localizedDescription
                } else if self.userNameTextField.text == "" || self.userNameTextField.text!.count <= 3 {
                    self.errorLabel.text = "Please enter a valid username"
                } else {
                    //Navigate to the ChatViewController
                    let db = Firestore.firestore()
                    
                    db.collection("users").addDocument(data: ["username": self.userNameTextField.text!, "uid": authResult!.user.uid]) { (error) in
                        if let e = error {
                            self.errorLabel.text = e.localizedDescription
                        }
                    }
                    
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMap", sender: self)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You create the account with the email and password, and only then after that check for a username. Wouldn't you be better to check for the username before trying to create the account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking for a username after you have created an account for the user, this is why you have an account regardless of having a username.

You should probably check that the username exists before creating the account. Using a `guard let` would allow you to check the username matches your criteria.

```
@IBAction func signupPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // check that the username exists and that it is of a valid length
    guard let username = self.userNameTextField.text, username.count > 3 else { 
        self.errorLabel.text = "Please enter a valid username"
        return 
    }
    
    if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
            if let e = error {
                self.errorLabel.text = e.localizedDescription
            } else {
                //Navigate to the ChatViewController
                let db = Firestore.firestore()
                
                db.collection("users").addDocument(data: ["username": username, "uid": authResult!.user.uid]) { (error) in
                    if let e = error {
                        self.errorLabel.text = e.localizedDescription
                    }
                }
                // This will navigate the user regardless of whether the
                // database update was successful or not.
                // You may want to reconsider this, and handle it in the above closure.
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMap", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

You also do not show any checks for email or password. You may wish to consider adding them as well. This is how I would fully refactor your code with checks for email and password, plus moving the `performSegue` call so that it only occurs if you do not get an error from adding the username.

```
@IBAction func signupPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // check that the username exists and that it is of a valid length
    guard let username = self.userNameTextField.text, username.count > 3 else { 
        self.errorLabel.text = "Please enter a valid username"
        return 
    }

    guard let password = passwordTextField.text else {
        self.errorLabel.text = "Please enter a valid password"
        return
    }

    guard let email = emailTextField.text else {
        self.errorLabel.text = "Please enter a valid email"
        return
    }
    
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
        if let e = error {
            self.errorLabel.text = e.localizedDescription
        } else {
            //Navigate to the ChatViewController
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            
            db.collection("users").addDocument(data: ["username": username, "uid": authResult!.user.uid]) { (error) in
                if let e = error {
                    // You may not want to show this error to the user but you should still show a "sanitised" error so that it doesn't leak information.
                    self.errorLabel.text = e.localizedDescription
                } else {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMap", sender: self)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code `if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text` you are checking if the string reference is not `nil`. You also want to know if this string is not equal to `""`.

In this case, we can use the convenience getter: `isEmpty`.

Final code example:

```
@IBAction func signupPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text {
            guard !email.isEmpty, !password.isEmpty else { return }
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
                if let e = error {
                    self.errorLabel.text = e.localizedDescription
                } else if self.userNameTextField.text == "" || self.userNameTextField.text!.count <= 3 {
                    self.errorLabel.text = "Please enter a valid username"
                } else {
                    //Navigate to the ChatViewController
                    let db = Firestore.firestore()
                    
                    db.collection("users").addDocument(data: ["username": self.userNameTextField.text!, "uid": authResult!.user.uid]) { (error) in
                        if let e = error {
                            self.errorLabel.text = e.localizedDescription
                        }
                    }
                    
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMap", sender: self)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```